# Cant display images on web page, where image path is stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, ftp

I am trying display images on webpage, where image path stored in database and images is stored in server.But i am not able to display those images using following codes, so pls somebody help me with this issue,..

```
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file_upload.php">
<table>

<?php

$dbhost = 'xxxxxxxx';
$dbuser = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$db_name = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$tbl_name = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$query1 = mysql_query("select * from '$tbl_name' where id='1'");
$rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
$path1 = $rows1['image'];

$query2 = mysql_query("select * from '$tbl_name' where id='2'");
$rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
$path2 = $rows2['image'];

$query3 = mysql_query("select * from '$tbl_name' where id='3'");
$rows3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3);
$path3 = $rows3['image'];

echo '<tr><td><img src="$path1"></td>' ;
echo '<td><img src="$path2"></td>' ;
echo '<td><img src="$path3"></td></tr>' ;

?>

</form>
</table>
```

output printing $path1, $path2 and $path3 only,../

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your query like this

All of them

```
 $query1 = mysql_query("select * from ".$tbl_name." where id='1'") or die(mysql_error());
```

You are passing your $path variable as string change that

Like this

```
echo "<tr><td><img src='".$path1."'></td>";
```

Comment: still displaying `<img src="$path1">` in output

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''imagetype1' where id='1'' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

Please correct this lines :

```
echo "<tr><td><img src='$path1'></td>" ;
echo "<td><img src='$path2'></td>" ;
echo "<td><img src='$path3'></td></tr>" ;
```

Its about quotes  :)

Answer (score 0):

use
HTML + PHP like

```
<tr><td><img src='<?php echo $path;?>'></td>
```

Comment: @Redsun , it clearly means  `$path;` is not having value ,check if associated record is present or not in DBase

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''imagetype1' where id='1'' at line 1

Comment: @Redsun , yes , Please check mysql Manual

Comment: @Redsun , Query is not properly executed by php code :) check it